# Pure Data help. How to use conditional logic in Pd

Tags: puredata

I've confused my myself a lot and need your help.
I'm trying to make a little function in Pure Data which says when the `toggle` is on it sends a `1` but when it isn't on it allows the computed value through.

So the program works a value `1` or `2` and when the `toggle` isn't on the computed value goes through, but when the `togggle` is on it sends `1` through.

I would show my code but its Pd so I can't copy and paste it. My attempt so far is making use of `spigots` but that isn't working its still sending `1` through no matter what the `toggle` is doing, and I know for a fact the computed value changes.

In normal code I would do something like:

```
value = computedVal

if (toggle == 1) then return 1;

else return value;
```

Answer (score 7):

Much simpler solution, and you can set the toggle value to any number, 0 is off, any number larger than 0 is on.

[image: Solution]

Comment: simpler than which solution? also, so far *every* answer to this question had "0 is *off*, any other number is *on*"

Comment: @umläute than everything containing more than 4 objects like here - expressions are the most easiest to read, don't need help to resolve unknown blocks and no externals also not falling into following wires and  hot-cold inlet logic... they are easier for everybody that used to learn other languages like procedural, structural, objective, functional etc. all non-flow-based ;-)

Answer (score 5):

There is more than one way to solve this. Assuming that you want a `1` to be sent out each time the `computedVal` changes while `toggle` is `1`, it could look like this:

[image: conditional statement]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using a demultiplexer idiom:

[image]

It basically prefixes the incoming message with a label (`0` or `1`), and then routes the data accordingly.

In general, you should learn to think in *data flow*, rather than *control flow*: how do you get the data to that part of the patch where it is needed.
Trying to mimick *control flow* (`if ... then ...`, or worse `while ... do ...`) will only melt your brains.

Comment: [list prepend 0] does not work in Pure Data vanilla. Is it provided by some external?

Comment: it does work with Pd vanilla since Pd-0.40 or so. It is hard to imagine that you use a version so old, so you probably just did a typo.

Comment: Very strange. Thank you for responding because I tried again today, and it worked fine. I know I didn't make a typo in Pure Data before I made my previous comment, as I tried it several times, so Pure Data must have been in a weird state. I'm on the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

It's best to keep the flow in the same type from start to finish (in this case a *float*). You can make a solution using only [f ], [pack], [t b], [t b f], and [route] objects. Maybe a [swap] if you're feeling fancy. The [spigot] object is more useful for *not* sending messages.

Also, if I understand correctly, you might be having trouble with [toggle] itself. The [toggle] object will be *on* given any non-zero value and *off* with a zero value. If you are giving [toggle] a one(1) or a two(2) it will act as if it's *on* in both cases. You could use [==] to fix this which will output a true(1) or a false(0) but only if you supply an argument like [== 1]. This way two(2) will register as a zero(0), turn [toggle] *off*, and return your value.

Two examples of alternative solutions:

[image: two alternative solutions]

Honestly though, for less headaches and *re*usability and simplicity, you should consider picking a pattern in your workflow similar to Pure Data 's inherent true(1) and false(0) paradigm. It will make logic a lot simpler in your future endeavors and is much more similar to the c-logic in which Pure Data is coded and emulates.

This way, if your logic statement accepts or returns a zero(0) as false and a non-zero as true, it will work more 'logically' with other pre-built Pure Data objects. Then your logic might look like the screen below.

More cohesive conditional logic:

[image: more cohesive conditional logic]

I hope it helps!